# Hacker Rank SQL problem | Problem using count() and MINUS | Weather Observation Station 4

Tags: sql, count, distinct

[image: 1]

I used

```
SELECT CITY 
FROM STATION
MINUS
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION;
```

Should I use `count()` to get the number of the elements in each column or does `MINUS` automatically get the numbers?

BTW the code didn't work as an answer even when I used `count()`.

The link:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-4/problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query does not do what you want. `MINUS` is a set-based operator, while what you need is aggregation. Here, you can take the difference between `COUNT(*)` (that's the total number of rows in the table) and `COUNT(DISTINCT city)` (that's the count of distinct values in column `city`):

```
select count(*) - count(distinct city) result
from station
```